# UIButton gets clicked twice

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I need to programmatically click a button: `[play sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];` 
But when I do that the void was called twice! I need to start a AVPlayer (in ViewDidLoad), but the music started twice too. Please help :).

The play code:

```
- (IBAction)playStream:(id)sender  {
    NSLog(@"%@", @"PlayStream clicked: ", sender);
        if(clicked == 0) {
        clicked = 1;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
        [self becomeFirstResponder];
        [play setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [playerr play];
    }
    else {
        [playerr stop];
        [play setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Start"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [audio setActive:NO error:nil];
        clicked = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Please clean up your code.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know how to do that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
@implementation MyClassName{
     BOOL musicPlaying;
}

- (IBAction)playStream:(id)sender  {
    if(musicPlaying){
        [self pauseMusic];
    }else{
        [self playMusic];
    }
}

-(void)playMusic{
    musicPlaying= YES;
    [play setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [playerr play];
}

-(void)pauseMusic{
    musicPlaying= NO;
    [playerr stop];
    [play setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Start"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [audio setActive:NO error:nil];
}
```

Now instead of tapping the button programmatically, just call playMusic or pauseMusic.

Comment: Thank you, I just fixed it myself.... But your code is working :) Now im using: (playerr.playbackState ==! MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying). I changed AVPlayer to a hidden MPMoviePlayer (for audio streaming)